# Python: sharing sqlite cursor with two classes only, plus the database

Tags: python, sqlite, class, csv, cursor

I have a script built using procedural programming that uses a sqlite database file. The script processes a CSV file, then uses a standard cursor to pass its particulars to a single SQLite DB.

After this, the script extracts from the DB to produce a number of spreadsheets in Excel via xlwt.

The problem with this is that the script only handles one input file at a time, whereas I will need to be iterating through about 70-90 of these files on any given day.

I've been trying to rewrite the script as object-oriented, but I'm having trouble with sharing the cursor.

The original input file comes in a zip archive that I would extract via Linux or Mac OS X command lines. Previously this was done manually; now I've managed to write classes and loop through totally ad-hoc numbers of multiple input files via the multi version of tkfiledialog.

Furthermore the original input file (ie one of the 70-90) is a text file in csv format with a DRF extension (obv., not really important) that gets picked by a simple tkfiledialog box:

```
    FILENAMER = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Open file", \
        filetypes=[("txt file",".DRF"),("txt file", ".txt"),\
                ("All files",".*")])
```

The DRF file itself is issued daily by location and date, ie 'BHP0123.DRF' is for the BHP location, issued for 23 January. To keep everything as straightforward as possible the procedural script further decomposes the DRF to just the BHP0123 part or prefix, then uses it to build a SQLite DB.

```
    FBASENAME  = os.path.basename(FILENAMER)
    FBROOT     = os.path.splitext(FBNAMED)[0]

    OUTPUTDATABASE = 'sqlite_' + FBROOT + '.db'
```

Basically with the program as a procedural script I just had to create one DB, one connection and one cursor, which could be shared by all the functions in the script:

```
    conn   = sqlite3.connect(OUTPUTDATABASE)   # <-- originally :: Is this the core problem?
    curs   = conn.cursor()
    conn.text_factory   = sqlite3.OptimizedUnicode
```

In the procedural version these variables above are global.

Procedurally I have

1) one function to handle formatting, and

2) another to handle the calculations needed. The DRF is indexed with about 2500 fields per row; I discard the majority and only use about 400-500 of these per row.

The formatting function parses out the CSV via a for-loop (discards junk characters, incomplete data, etc), then passes the formatted data for the calculator to process and chew on. The core problem seems to be that on the one hand I need the DB connection to be constant for each input DRF file, but on the other that connection can only be shared by the formatter and calculator, and 'regenerated' for each DRF.

Crucially, I've tried to rewrite as little of the formatter and calculator as possible.

I've tried to create a separate dbcxn class, then create an instance to share, but I'm confused as to how to handle the output DB situation with the cursor (and pass it intact to both formatter and calculator):

```
    class DBcxn(object):
        def __init__(self, OUTPUTDATABASE):
            OUTPUTDATABASE  = ?????
            self.OUTPUTDATABASE = OUTPUTDATABASE

        def init_db_cxn(self, OUTPUTDATABASE):
            conn        = sqlite3.connect(OUTPUTDATABASE) # < ????
            self.conn   = conn
            curs        = conn.cursor()
            self.curs   = curs
            conn.text_factory = sqlite3.OptimizedUnicode

    dbtest = DBcxn( ???? )
```

If anyone might suggest a way of untangling this I'd be very grateful. Please let me know if you need more information.

Cheers
Massimo Savino